# Coffescript parseInt shortcut?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, type-conversion, shortcut

In javascript I can do something similar to this

```
1 === +'1' #true
```

in coffeescript since everything is strictly checked how can I do something similar as a shortcut?

I know `1 is parseInt("1")` is possible but it's much more verbose.

Comment: In JavaScript, it is evaluated as so `1 === +'1'` -> `1 === 1` -> `true` (that is, the unary `+` operator is applied *first* and strict equality applies). Not really sure what is meant otherwise. In any case, `+numStr` is *not* equivalent to parseInt as it yields any number, not strictly an integer (or NaN). The ASM way to write "as integer" is `num | 0`, but that limits to 32-bit, signed and it still differs as seen by `parseInt("foo")` vs `"foo" | 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unary plus operator can be applied to strings in CoffeeScript, just like in JavaScript.

```
coffee> 1 == +"1"
true
coffee> 1 is +"1"
true
```

However, there is no `===` in CoffeeScript.

Comment: There is a `===` in CoffeeScript, they just call it `==` or `is`.